# Replace list element in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, replace

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,[4,5],["apple","pear"]]})
df.replace({[4,5]:4.5})
df.replace({["apple","pear"]:"apple"})
```

Here I got TypeError. I want to replace specific lists and there is no any regulation between the list which is to be replaced and the object used to replace the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *not* a trivial problem, because DataFrames are not designed to work with mutable objects like lists, sets, or dicts.

You can determine the index of match and replace accordingly.

```
m = [v == [4, 5] for v in df['a']] 
df.loc[m, 'a'] = 4.5

df
               a
0              1
1              2
2              3
3            4.5
4  [apple, pear]
```

A similar procedure follows for `['apple', 'pair']`. You can form a function from this if you so wish:

```
def replace(df, col, key, val):
    m = [v == key for v in df[col]]
    df.loc[m, col] = val

replace(df, 'a', [4, 5], 4.5)
replace(df, 'a', ['apple', 'pear'], 'apple')

df
       a
0      1
1      2
2      3
3    4.5
4  apple
```

Note: The function works in-place.

Answer (score 2):

There is one way using `astype` , Even it work , but I still highly recommend you using [cold's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50322899/7964527)

```
df.astype(str).replace({'[4, 5]':4.5,"['apple', 'pear']":"apple"})
Out[159]: 
       a
0      1
1      2
2      3
3    4.5
4  apple
```

Comment: Yeah... I thought about this, but the scope for errors is just too large (quoting issues, etc etc).

Comment: Last thing, it converts all items to str, even numeric ones ;-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes, that is why I think your answer is the right way for this type of question

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, since the places I had listed on a column needed to be standardized. First I tried to give a list as key and the standard word as value, which of course failed. So, I made a function to expand the values on the list as keys, and assign the standard word as value for all of them:

```
def list_to_dict(cities):
    new_dict = {}
    for key in cities:
        value = cities[key]
        for item in value:
            new_dict[item] = key
    
    return new_dict
```

With this, I got to clean this list of words aimed to mean Mexico City in Spanish (of course my set is larger and for more places, but this is an illustrative sub-group):

```
ciudades = list_to_dict({'Ciudad De Mexico' : ['Ciudad De México', 'Cuajimalpa De Morelos', 'Mexicocity', 'Ciudad De  Mexico', 'Miguel Hidalgo, Cdmx', 'Df', 'Cmx', 'Ciudad De M', 'Cdmx', 'Ciudad De M?Xico', 'C.D. M.X,', 'Mx-Cdm', 'Cuidad De Mexico', 'Dif', 'D.F.', 'D.F', 'DF', 'Distrito', 'Mexico City', 'Coyoacan', 'Mx-Cdm', 'Cdmex', 'Mx-Dif', 'Mexico Df', 'Ciudad_De_M']}
```

Resulting in:

[image: result]